# Accessing a variable from a C file in CPP file

Tags: c++, c

I've got a program where I'm forced to meld together some C and C++ code. I've got some global variables defined in C and I need to access them in both C and C++ files but can't figure it out. Here's what I have, which works in C files, but not in CPPs:

C.h

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#ifndef _COMMON_H_
#define _COMMON_H_

extern char test[100];

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

C.c

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "C.h"

char test[100] = "value";
```

CPlusPlus.cpp

```
#include "C.h"

int TestFunction() {
    // I need to access variable test here
}
```

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: So what doesn't work? Compiler error? Linker? Runtime?

Comment: You are missing an `#endif` in `C.h`.

Comment: Also, `_COMMON_H_` is illegal.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: "illegal"?  What jurisdiction has passed a law against it?  What is the penalty or fine?

Comment: @StephenCanon I don't know how it is over there, but over here, dereferencing a NULL pointer will get you 2 to 5...

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: if only it were so =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > Assuming the question is ‟how do I access the variable `test` here?”

Like this:

```
#include "C.h"
#include <cstring>
int TestFunction() {
  return strcmp(test, "volvo");
}
```

Comment: That's what I was doing. I have no idea why it was returning a blank string, but a clean and rebuild made it start working. Very odd.